# Android ListViewAdapter return wrong position after adding more data and invoking setSelection() method

Tags: android, listview, getview

I currently lost in a problem that I have a list which displays ImageViews when the ListView scroll to the top I will add more data to the list and make the ListView still show the current image instead of the first image from the list. So I use the setSelection method after data changing and the invoking of notifyDatasetHasChanged().But when I scroll the List one more time after the above invokes, I get wrong position in the getView() method from the adapter.

Here is the code:

```
for (int i = tempPics.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    DBChapterPicture pic = (DBChapterPicture) tempPics.get(i);
    chapterPics.add(0, pic);
}

detailAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
detailListView.setSelection(chapterPics.size() - headState - 1);
```

And after this piece executed in the getView() of my adapter I got wrong position:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{}
```

I don't know why. I think it may caused by the setSelection() method.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Q1: Why is every loop's `chapterPics.add` adding your `pic` object to index 0? Q2: What is the value of `headState`?

Comment: A1:I want the newly added pics on the top of the list. A2:headState is the value of offset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been solved.I set the ImageView's size before the image data has loaded and the height I set is very large, as large as five times of the screen height.So the ListView only create one cell when the adapter is set to it.This caused the wrong position problem.

Answer (score 0):

Set the setTag and getTag method in your getView() method using Holder Class Object like :

```
if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new Holder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_row_layout, null);
            holder.img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgId);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
        }



class Holder {
        public ImageView img;
    }
```

Comment: It's the position pass in the getView() method went wrong, I think It's nothing to do with the holder.

Comment: Try with interface @AirTayork

Comment: what do you mean by interface?

Comment: you can implement method in your activity and get the actual position with interface.  First of all Create Interface with one method with int parameter and implement in your activity and Make object in adapter and call your interface method from getView() clicklistner or wherever you want.

Comment: It's been solved.I set the ImageView's size before the image data has loaded and the height I set is very large, as large as five times of the screen height.So the ListView only create one cell when the adapter is set to it.This caused the wrong position problem through I havent'